# how to invoke jquery-ui dialog which is in iframe from parent page

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am creating a form using Jquery-ui. Buttons are in parent page and codes are in another page, which is embeded into parent page through iframe. can anyone tell me how can I invoke dialog function of Jquery-ui from parent page's button.

```
$( "#comment" ) 
.button()
 .click(function() 
{ parent.I1.f1(); });
```

//I1 is the frame id
 here is a button

```
<button id="comment" name="comment">Comment</button>
```

### This is on the parent page.

In another page(Iframe page)

```
function f1(){
 $("#comment" ).dialog("open"); 
}
```

is defined details and code of dialog box is here

jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/modal-form.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Invoking javascript in iframe from parent page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/251420/invoking-javascript-in-iframe-from-parent-page)

Comment: I am able to reach iframe function. but from the iframe page  i need to invoke this function $("#comment" ).dialog("open"); but it's not invoking.this function is in the iframe itself.

Comment: does it throw an error? just wrap your call with a `try/catch` and `alert` the error

Comment: without a proper test environment we can't help you further.

Comment: you can edit your own post and add this info right? If it's part of the question, should always be there, not as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Give your iframe an ID (eg myiframe), and then do something like this:

```
document.getElementById('myiframe').contentWindow.function();
```

Where `function()` is the function you want to execute.

Remember that the page in your iframe needs to be on the same domain as the parent page for this to work.

Comment: I am able to reach iframe function. but from the iframe page i need to invoke this function $("#comment" ).dialog("open"); but it's not invoking.this function is in the iframe itself.

Comment: `document.getElementById('myiframe').contentWindow.$("#comment" ).dialog("open");`

Answer (score 0):

First, **it will only work** if the same domains are exactly the same, in other words, the `iframe` needs to belong to the same url, if not, **a cross-browser exception will be thrown**.

To call javascript methods on other frames, you can find thousands of articles out there for this, you simply read an existing answer

> [Invoking JavaScript code in an iframe from the parent page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251420/invoking-javascript-in-iframe-from-parent-page)